# How to use MIDI keyboard for note input in Cubase?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, cubase

I have a Yamaha YPT-220 and Cubase 7.5. I would like to be able to set up a configuration that would allow me to press keys on my keyboard and have it play through Cubase, using the selected instrument track program. (Being able to input notes [record MIDI, basically] would be great too.) How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Asian Squirrel, you can either buy a MIDI to USB cable, which I would not recommend because of the latency. Latency is the delay between when you press a key and when it registers in your DAW as a midi note. If you're interested in the MIDI to USB cable, here's a link:

http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Uno

It's the cheapest option.

You can also buy an audio interface, which is what I would suggest. I seem to get less latency using an audio interface. I've had a wholly positive experience with the focusrite scarlett series:

http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Scarlett2i4

If you opt for the audio interface, bear in mind that you will also need to procure a midi cable.

Comment: Haha oops forgot to mention that I've got the MIDI-USB cable (even got it connected to where Cubase recognizes it and knows when it's been disconnected). But how do I configure it so my keypresses are registered in some manner?

Comment: I haven't used Cubase before, and I was under the assumption that you were just looking for ways to connect the keyboard. However, create a midi track within Cubase and make sure that you have some sort of Virtual instrument available. The usb-midi cable won't make the sounds that come on your keyboard available to the DAW. You're going to have to use a virtual instrument. Once you have a midi track on Cubase, assign your midi sound in the DAW or plug-in and then you should be able to produce sounds by pressing down on the keys.

Comment: Didn't work... I also tried using the Monitor button, and that didn't seem to do much either. Do I have to have a MIDI Device set up in the MIDI Devices manager thing?

Comment: There's no noticable MIDI latency whether the link is 5-pin into an interface or MIDI-over-USB.   There may well be a latency issue when the computer produces sound in response to the MIDI instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have already checked the manual of your Yamaha keyboard and it states that it can be used as a MIDI keyboard.
I am not sure about Cubase but it works fine with NUendo. And someone has told me that Cubase and Nuendo iterfaces are same.
Try the following

Add an Instrument track, then Select one of the available synths.e.g. Embracer
Now under "input" section of the track, the name of your keyboard should appear (you stated that the program recognizes once the keyboard is connected)
Select your keyboard as input.

Track output should show the synth that you have selected (embracer).
Select Embracer
Enable read/write and record on the track.

Play a few keys on the keyboard and you should hear the synth being played.Hit record and start playing and recording..
Hope this helps!!!